# Step function versus Sigmoid function

Tags: neural-network

I don't quite understand why a sigmoid function is seen as more useful (for neural networks) than a step function... hoping someone can explain this for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [(Heaviside) step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) is typically only useful within [single-layer perceptrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron), an early type of neural networks that can be used for classification in cases where the input data is [linearly separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_separability).

However, [multi-layer neural networks or multi-layer perceptrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayer_perceptron) are of more interest because they are general function approximators and they are able to distinguish data that is not linearly separable.

Multi-layer perceptrons are trained using [backpropapagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation). A requirement for backpropagation is a [differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function) activation function. That's because backpropagation uses [gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) on this function to update the network weights.

The Heaviside step function is non-differentiable at *x = 0* and its derivative is *0* elsewhere. This means gradient descent won't be able to make progress in updating the weights and backpropagation will fail.

The [sigmoid or logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) does not have this shortcoming and this explains its usefulness as an activation function within the field of neural networks.

Comment: This is a beautiful answer. Builds up the required context and comes in for the kill. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the problem you are dealing with. In case of simple binary classification, a step function is appropriate. Sigmoids can be useful when building more biologically realistic networks by introducing noise or uncertainty. Another but compeletely different use of sigmoids is for numerical continuation, i.e. when doing bifurcation analysis with respect to some parameter in the model. Numerical continuation is easier with smooth systems (and very tricky with non-smooth ones).

Comment: I think the most common case for sigmoid activation is simply regression.